# Parse parameter to bool or just use string in switch statement

Tags: go

I'm coming across a few situations where I would like to use routing to change some `Is_Active` fields in my database but I'm curious about performance.

Let's have a route handler as so:

```
func testHandler(r *mux.Router) {
    r.HandleFunc("/test/{status}" statusHandler).Methods("GET")
}
```

Now that parameter will only ever be 0 or 1, unless the user tries something else but either way nothing will happen unless it's  0 or 1. My question is, is it faster to parse the string into a boolean which would involve bringing in the `strconv` package or would it be faster to just do a switch on the string?

Example of both:

```
func statusHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    v := mux.Vars(r)
    active, err := strconv.ParseBool(v["status"])
    // Handle err

    if active {
      // Do something
    } else {
      // Do something else
    }
}
```

or

```
func statusHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    v := mux.Vars(r)

    switch v["status"] {
        case "0":
            // Do something
        case "1":
            // Do something else
        default:
            // Throw 500 Error
    }
}
```

Comment: The speed of parsing `0` or `1` is not even measurable in the course of an http request. Use whichever is more convenient.

Comment: @JimB Well to do that the whole `strconv` package has to be imported, doesn't that affect performance?

Comment: You're already parsing a text protocol, HTTP, which requires the `strconv` pacakge (and it's used in the `fmt` package which is probably already imported too). Also, simply importing the package has no bearing on performance.

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy, Go is a statically compiled language, so nothing "imported" gets somehow "loaded at runtime". Importing a package merely means adding the necessary pieces of its code to the binary image of the executable program being prepared by the compiler and the linker. So no, importing a package does not incur runtime costs.

Comment: @kostix Thanks for the explanation, coming from node I wanted to avoid the using a bundle of packages that would just slow my program down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could see the source code of `ParseBool` [here](https://golang.org/src/strconv/atob.go?s=351:391#L1). It uses switch too but with more cases. If the compiler inlines its code it, speed should be very similar to your code. If you want a definite answer you should benchmark different cases.

In general I discourage you from paying attention to this small details. It's just matter of some nano seconds but it make your codes more difficult to understand. Begin optimizations with profiling your code to find hotspots that take a lot of time and fix them.